# How to reverse a string in Python on a word-by-word basis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How to reverse each word in a sentence without affecting special characters in Python?

Suppose input:

```
" Hi, I am vip's "
```

Output should be like:

```
" iH, I ma piv's"
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```
inp = " Hi, I am vip's "
output = re.sub(r'\w+', lambda x: x.group(0)[len(x.group(0))::-1], inp)
print(inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
 Hi, I am vip's 
 iH, I ma piv's
```

Comment: `[::-1]` will do just fine as a slice expression…

Comment: @deceze Well it looks like you've _sliced_ through my answer quite well `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>> strung = 'this is my string'
>> ' '.join(x[::-1] for x in strung.split())
'siht si ym gnirts'
```

Comment: Yes, This works.